# How does http://user:pass@host.com authentication work?

Tags: http, web, http-authentication

Can anyone explain how http://user:pass@host.com authentication works? Does the browser send the `Authorization` header with `user:pass` being base-64 encoded?

I opened the Net console in Chrome developer tools and when I do request such as `http://user:pass@stackoverflow.com` I do not see `Authorization` header being added.

I am really curious to how the browser sends the password in case I use `user:pass@` in front of a URL.

Comment: It is just the authorisation headers. I don't know how Chrome does it, but with Firefox it checks if the site is asking for authentication (in the request) and if it isn't, warns you that `You are about to log in to the site "stackoverflow.com" with the username "user", but the website does not require authentication. This may be an attempt to trick you.

Is "stackoverflow.com" the site you want to visit?` And then it either [Yes] cuts out the auth details or [No] aborts the request. So unless you've got a site with authorisation handy, you *won't* see the headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To inspect headers, you need to test against a server that requires authentication. The client will not send any `Authorization` header until the server asks for it since the client won't know what authentication method the server requires (basic or digest).

---

HTTP authentication is done in two requests:

First, a request without any `Authorization` header is sent.
The server then responds with a `WWW-Authenticate` that tells the client how to authenticate. This includes a realm name and an authentication method (again, this is either basic or digest)

The client then sends a new request with an additional `Authorization` header. In the case of [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), this header is just `user:pass` base64 encoded, just as you are saying:

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz
```

Now the password is visible in transit, unless you are using https. A better option is [digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_Access_Authentication), where the contents of both `WWW-Authenticate` and `Authorization` are best explained by the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_Access_Authentication). :)

Comment: Thanks - this answer led me to this example: https://gist.github.com/neolitec/8953607